# How to check type compatibility when using the typing module?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm using Python PEP484 type hints to write a type-checker for a DSL I've written in Python. If I have a function expecting type `T` for one of its arguments, and it's being called with an expression of type `S`, how can I check whether the call is valid? Is using `issubclass(S, T)` enough? If so, why does `mypy` have such a complicated `is_subtype` check? Or should I just use the `mypy` version?

**Edit**: Here's an example to clarify what I mean. The DSL has a function defined as:

```
T = TypeVar('T', float, str)
def op_add(operand1: T, operand2: T) -> T:
    "Number addition or string concatenation."
    # In this DSL, `+` cannot be used with lists
    return operand1 + operand2  # Rely on Python overloading of `+`
```

Then a user types in an expression which is parsed into a syntax tree, with a branch that could be: `node = OperatorNode('+', Literal([5.0]), Variable("abc"))`. We don't know the value of the `abc` variable yet, but lists can never be used with `+`, so I want to raise a `TypeError` to alert the user.

If I do `issubclass(typing.List[float], var)`, that gives me False, so I can raise an error right away. My question is whether this check is guaranteed to work across cases as I build out the DSL, or if I need to use a more complex check like `mypy`

Comment: I've used an ABC and then defined the functions to expect the ABC and not the subClasses, and mypy has never complained. What exactly doe it say for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`issubclass` check is sufficient if neither argument to `issubclass` includes constructs from `typing` module such as `Union`, `Callable`, `Any`, generics, etc.

`typing` constructs exist in python runtime as a shadow of their true form, that is they don't support many of the operations that make sense conceptually:

```
issubclass(List[int], List[int])  # runtimem error
issubclass(List[int], List) # True (as expected)
issubclass(str, Union[str]) # runtime error
issubclass(Union[str], str) # True (as expected)
issubclass(Union[int, str], str) # runtime error
```

Sometimes `issubclass` will work with `typing` constructs, but in general, it may raise an exception or give an incorrect answer; you'll need to figure out what to do on a case by case basis.

`mypy` has a more complicated `is_subtype` because it does need to handle all the `typing` constructs, and even then there is still some work to be done there.

Comment: In Python 3.7 `issubclass(List[int], List)` raises TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks